# Concatenar expressões do aps.net com texto literal

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho essa expressão:

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Analista") %>' runat="server" /><br />
```

O resultado dela é Aprovado ou Reprovado. Gostaria de acrescentar a seguinte palavra: por: No qual o resultado final seria:

Aprovado/Reprovado por:

Como eu faço isso? Tentei com o por: dentro da aspa simples, tentei com + dentro d aspa simples, tentei fora e nenhuma das alternativas deu certo.

Comment: E se fizeres `<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Analista") %>' runat="server" /><label>&nbsp por:</label><br />`?? Ou até sem meter a `<label>`

Comment: Deu certo, mas as fontes são diferentes. O por: ficou bem pequeno. Fiz assim e deu certo: <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Situacao") %>' runat="server" />por:></label><br />

Comment: Exacto, assim também deve dar. Só não sugeri porque pensei que já tinhas tentado

Comment: Nem pensei em fazer assim, sério mesmo. Mas resolvi assim: <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Situacao") %>' runat="server" /><asp:Label Text="por:" runat="server" /><br />

Comment: Disse te para usares a tag `<label>` porque podiam ter as mesmas propriedades css que `<asp:Label />`, mas pronto, ta resolvido ;)

Comment: @CesarMiguel, poste sua sugestão para eu finalizar como sua a solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro que acrescentes no fim da tua `<asp:Label />` o texto "por:", ficando:

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Analista") %>' runat="server" /><label>&nbsp por:</label><br />
```

A partida se não tiveres problemas com o CSS não terás problemas de fonte